# C++ Code Clarification - NameSpaces

Tags: c++

So I'm reviewing for a test and I'm looking at this code here:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace acme
{
int map;
/* ** */enum day{one,two};
/* ** */void fun1(day d);
int cout; **
}
void main(){
    acme::map = 1;
    /* ** */void fun2(acme::day d); 
    cout << acme::map << endl;
    using namespace acme;
    map = 2;
    /* ** */void fun3(day d);
    std::cout << map << endl;
}
```

My question is this: What are the lines that are denoted with a " ** " at the end for? Like, what do they do? I excluded one of starred lines in main and nothing changed.

Comment: It looks like "**" is a syntax error. I cant compile your code with those stars appearing at the end.

Comment: they called syntax errors

Comment: You should just remove them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the stars myself to note the lines I was talking about. Bad placement, I'm sorry. Fixed the placement. I just need to know what those lines are meant to do.

Comment: Those are function prototypes. Don't really know what they are doing in `main` however.

Comment: main should also return an int, otherwise it won't compile. 

the fun# functions are prototypes (shouldn't be in main like 0x499602D2 said. 

enum is an enumeration. (basic c/c++ type)

Comment: when you say reviewing for a test, do you mean for testing or are you meant to answer a question in school test or something?

Comment: Like we're having a test on a few topics (Inheritance and Polymorphism, Class Hierarchies, Linked Lists, etc.) and this code was given to us as an example. I was just trying to understand what the parts I starred meant for the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
int map; // an int named map.
/* ** */enum day{one,two}; // the words one and two that can be used like a type.
/* ** */void fun1(day d); // An empty function.
int cout; // - I have no idea why anyone would do this. Basically it an int named cout. 
}
```

I think the point of this is just to show how namespace stops things from being global. So you can have an int with the same name if they are in different namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

all those lines you noted that starts with "void" are function declarations.

eg.
    void function1(int x);

if you make use of them, then you will need to add function definitions to them.

eg.

```
void function1(int x) 
{   
cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

The "enum" is a datatype that is inititializes its parameters to integers. (read up on it)